# How to access a main window element from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This has been asked before but most answers seem to assume that the parent window is also an iframe that can be selected.

I have a DIV in my parent window:

That I want to display if an error happens in an iFrame embedded on the page.

Here is my iFrame javascript I have attempted:

```
if ( x == "" || y == ""){
parent.document.getElementById("error").style.display ="block";
parent.document.getElementById("error").style.transition ="all 0.5s ease";
parent.document.getElementById("error").style.opacity ="1";
parent.document.getElementById("error_write").innerHTML = "Oops, looks like     you've missed an input field. Please ensure both fields are completed in order for the converter to work.";}
```

This doesn't seem to pull the "error" element from the parent window and display it. This code WORKS if not attempting to access element from another frame.

Please help.

Comment: Does `<iframe>` `.src` have same domain as parent `window`?

Comment: You need to use window.postMessage() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you've searched this out, but the answer will always be the same .. The reasoning that you cannot do this is **security** related ...  I understand you are trying to do something as benign as "passing an error"

However, Imagine this  -- What if you were a malicious person, loading a login page for, say, a bank in an `<iframe>` on your page --  And you were allowed to pass login variables **from** the `<iframe>` **to** your parent page ...  This of course is overly dramatic, however it **is** the reason most, if not ALL browsers disallow passing data between `<iframe>` and `parent`.

Comment: They are in the same domain. I've tried window.parent and window.opener but they haven't worked. But yes, I'm trying to pass an error through to a splash screen element  in the main window. I just can't get the iframe to display a parent element. :(

Comment: As I said .. Even on the same domain .. Generally considered taboo, and not possible.

Comment: Hence the fact you can access it from within the SAME FRAME ..  My answer is correct .. You cannot access an `<iframe>` from a parent window.  You are welcome to provide evidence to the contrary.